# Taking the derivative from a graph?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions

I have a problem that's graphed. It's linear from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$, then it's a horizontal line after that.

I have to find four derivatives from this, and I've never done a problem like this before. I have to find $f'(1/2)$, $\frac{d}{dx} f(e^x)$ at $x=0$, $\frac{d}{dx} f(e^{-x})$ at $x=1$, and $\frac{d}{dx} f(e^x)$ at $x=1$.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I've edited your question to use $\LaTeX$.  Please make sure it still represents your original intent.  For help with formatting in the future, please see [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks, it looks less confusing now!

Comment: I got 0 for f(e^-1). Did I do it right?

Comment: So the answers should be 1, DNE, -e, and e?

Comment: I like your first two answers, but not your second two... what's the derivative of the function for all $x \gt 1$?

Comment: Could it be, 0?

Comment: Yes, $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\gt1$.  Why?  Well, we have a horizontal line, and (by definition) the slope is $0$.

Comment: So my last two answers are 0? :D

Comment: yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: It says the third answer is wrong when I try to put it in. /: it's the e^-x one. Could it be -1/e?

Comment: It turned out to be -1/e. And I figured it out on my own thanks to your answer, so thank you very much!

Comment: so sorry about that one... I was trying to do them in my head, and goofed with that one. sorry.  But I'm glad you figured it out yourself!  `:)`  I wish you well in your calculus sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an exercise in the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

First, recall that the derivative of a function is basically a fancy term for the slope at a given point.  (At least, in a simplified form...)  So, to find $f'(a)$, look at the slope of the graph at $x=a$.  This should help with the first question.

For the rest, recall that $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x)) = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$.  So, for example, $\frac{d}{dx}f(e^x) = f'(e^x)\cdot e^x$.  You have the graph of the function, so you can find $f'(a)$ for a given value of $x=a$ as above.  You also can evaluate $e^x$ at any point.  This will help with the rest of the questions.  I will warn that not all points on that function are differentiable.

If you need more guidance, let me know via a comment.  I'm changing the way I leave answers to a more open-ended method, so I'm still gauging how much answering to give. `:)`

Comment: So, it would be f'(e^1) * {e^1} for x=1?

Comment: @sucksatmath Exactly.

Comment: So the answer is e, right?

Comment: Not quite...  What's $f'(e^1)=f'(e)$?  (remember that $e \approx 2.71$, so it's greater than $1$)

Comment: I'm stumped on this one.